# Can we access the internal array of a Android Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, pixel

Does an Android Bitmap function similar to a BufferedImage? When you get the internal pixel buffer as an int[] or as a byte[] and update the values inside them, the image changes. Is that the same case as a Bitmap?